# sharepoint list calculated value syntax error

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I have a optinal number column "Sıra Numarası" and I want to create a column based on that value but coulndt fix the syntax error that sharepoint talking about..

Searched many but cant figure the problem out here..
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I presume you environment requires **,** as separator and not **;**

If you just do `=Aktif` and it works and `=Baslik` (with that special character s) does not,

Then I think the problem is the DisplayName.. you can easily try by changing the displayname to a normal s